# Tried adding adview in webview but the ad just scrolls along with the webpage

Tags: android, webview

At first I tried using Vertical Linear layot and added webview and adview within the app but the app just crashes. The below xml works but the ad scrolls along with the static webpage. 
I'm new to programming as general and I learnt some HTML in school so I used static webpages to code the app whilst using webview in java.
I also tried this :
[Align AdView (AdMob) to bottom of screen with WebView on Android Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922649/align-adview-admob-to-bottom-of-screen-with-webview-on-android-layout) to no avail. I tried googling but nothing seems to help. How do I fix the ad to bottom of the screen ? This is my first attempt at creating an android app.

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
</WebView>
```

My java code is :

```
public class Book extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    WebView mWebView = null;
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/book.html");
}
```

}

Comment: why are you making the adview a child of the webview?

Comment: I tried used Linear layout and added webview and adview as children but  the ad appears at the top of the screen and blocks the contents of the static webpage.

Comment: try my awnser, i set the `webview` above the `adview` i didn't test it but i believe it will work

Comment: It says unfortuantely the app has stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView 
       android:id="@+id/webview"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       ads:adSize="BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "replace");
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId("youtAdId");
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
WebView mWebView = null;
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.pt");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) . But the ad sits at bottom at first but is still scrolling along with the webpage.

Comment: give me a second i will try to run this on my phone

Comment: I think this xml code is working but my java code is wrong. I am searching now. :)

Comment: Edit your question and post the stacktrace it's easier to find the problem

Comment: Check my edit, i tested this on my phone and it's fully working the ad stays on the bottom even when you scroll, if this was helpfull don't forget to accept the awnser :)

Comment: THANK YOU !!!! apparently I copied your code without looking at it and forgot to add adsize and id . IT said :                      at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main

(XposedBridge.java:132)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad 

size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.

Comment: you are welcome :), yhe i know, when i tried running on my phone i also got that message and i realised my mistake